# fixed div sits on top of another div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a fixed div at the bottom of my page, but it is covering up another div that is behind it. How can I make it where the markup behind the fixed div can be scrolled? My end goal is to have the buttons fixed at the very bottom but if the content is behind the buttons then allow the scrollbar to show. I tried adding an `over-flow:auto`, but it didn't change. My assumption why that didn't work is because the viewport does think that the `div` behind the button is viewable...But the fixed position div just has a higher z value so it's just going to cover it anyways. I don't want to add any padding to accommodate the empty space.

**Parent Container**

```
.page-container {
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  .page-title {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  .page-title-fixed {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background: $bgGray;
    z-index: 999;

    .page-title { margin-bottom: 0; }
  }
}
```

**Fixed Buttons styling**

```
  style={{
      position: 'fixed',
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      height: 60,
      width: '100%',
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6',
      borderTop: '1px solid #e0e0e0'
    }}
```

[image: You can see the white box hiding behind the fixed buttons]

Comment: What's the behaviour you are expecting? your problem is that you reach the end of the page and some content is behind the fixed div? you can add a bottom padding for that but your question is not clear

Comment: @arieljuod, I updated my question. Hopefully that clarified it. I did think about adding bottom padding. But this may be viewed on larger screen and it will look weird with the extra space.

Comment: You can remove/add the padding using media queries if you don't want the padding for large screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to have a fixed element, but you need to be able to scroll down through body content without the fixed element obscuring the body content?

If so, the simplest way is to add padding to the bottom of the body content equivalent to (or higher) than the fixed element. This will ensure that as you scroll all the way down you won't have text fall behind the fixed element.

(If I misunderstood please clarify and I'll try to help further)

```css
.content {
width: 100%;
height:90%;
padding: 20px;
font-family: sans-serif;
/* This doesn't let the text fall behind the fixed element */
padding-bottom: 90px;
}
.fixed {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background: #007ccc;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
padding: 30px 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin commodo tristique orci id tincidunt. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Etiam hendrerit, nisi non pharetra laoreet, mauris odio ultricies ligula, id convallis dolor augue vitae velit. Praesent condimentum metus at turpis consequat, sed posuere orci euismod. Suspendisse in quam facilisis, imperdiet dolor at, dignissim risus. Mauris ut libero ante. Donec porttitor nibh sit amet massa tristique efficitur. Aenean commodo vel nisi ac lacinia. Etiam in faucibus enim, eget vehicula sem. Etiam justo nunc, bibendum id ligula nec, ultrices accumsan lorem. Mauris imperdiet augue vitae vulputate efficitur. Donec id sapien dui. Nam lacus nibh, cursus sed laoreet a, feugiat id arcu. Cras sed ultricies nibh, pretium placerat augue.

Maecenas mattis arcu augue, interdum rhoncus mauris condimentum at. Donec pharetra eleifend tincidunt. Sed iaculis orci id ex dapibus scelerisque. Aenean euismod felis sit amet enim dictum, sed pellentesque nisi rutrum. Pellentesque iaculis massa non massa aliquam volutpat. Praesent interdum varius orci, in ullamcorper turpis eleifend at. Phasellus in cursus lacus, at ultricies mauris. Pellentesque tristique tellus non pharetra vulputate. Proin sodales felis est, sit amet ornare turpis blandit eu.

Nulla finibus purus vel elit vehicula, ut tincidunt diam suscipit. Nullam sed congue nisi, eget venenatis felis. Integer hendrerit est sit amet elementum tempor. Duis molestie mi id consequat semper. Donec rutrum sed lectus et pellentesque. Vestibulum sit amet ligula elit. Donec et felis at mi volutpat finibus. Suspendisse vitae libero gravida, gravida erat non, mattis turpis. Cras facilisis porta diam, vel molestie libero hendrerit sed. Proin imperdiet commodo metus non pulvinar. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean tristique elit eu blandit imperdiet. Suspendisse tincidunt turpis at orci tincidunt molestie. Vestibulum dapibus maximus augue, ut cursus ante convallis non.

Nulla id feugiat nulla, at placerat ipsum. Sed id turpis quis mauris vehicula eleifend vel at risus. Vestibulum dictum orci in augue finibus, a lacinia nisi rutrum. Cras vehicula sodales enim sit amet maximus. Donec in justo porta, volutpat mi eget, feugiat elit. Nunc bibendum bibendum quam sit amet pulvinar. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nam ipsum tellus, tincidunt nec laoreet sit amet, semper in lorem. Donec suscipit risus quis pellentesque porta. Duis ac felis lobortis, blandit purus eu, dapibus arcu. Nullam semper varius felis nec gravida. Nullam feugiat convallis porta.

Praesent mollis urna ex, a luctus dui tristique et. Nulla bibendum tristique erat, ac consequat ligula suscipit ut. Morbi turpis nulla, facilisis et maximus eu, pretium et magna. Integer egestas est id neque dictum ullamcorper. Etiam consequat dolor at nulla maximus, id dictum dui laoreet. Sed mattis ex in tortor malesuada sagittis. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas sapien erat, pretium ac dignissim nec, tincidunt ut nisi. Quisque tincidunt volutpat dui, ut vulputate nunc lobortis a. Mauris felis nisl, imperdiet varius iaculis sit amet, tempor ac erat. Proin sodales elementum finibus. Fusce ut ultricies nisl, sed venenatis justo. Pellentesque diam urna, semper et risus at, placerat finibus risus.

Sed sagittis mattis lorem, vitae dictum nunc egestas a. Sed pretium orci vitae ipsum pretium posuere. Sed commodo dui eget dignissim luctus. Nullam ullamcorper libero cursus libero lobortis, nec tempus eros varius. Fusce massa ligula, lacinia in quam sit amet, placerat ullamcorper tellus. Donec convallis justo non sem viverra hendrerit. Sed ac vestibulum ipsum, ac euismod augue. Donec tempus dignissim arcu in bibendum. Donec placerat vitae nunc consequat laoreet. Vivamus sagittis interdum arcu et interdum. Aliquam ullamcorper fringilla ultrices. Nulla tempus risus at interdum sagittis. Praesent ultrices, ex at viverra ultricies, lectus augue tempus justo, id luctus leo augue sed urna. Quisque nec mi et risus blandit volutpat. Nulla at purus in nunc tincidunt lacinia et eu libero.

Donec velit nibh, fringilla eu condimentum vitae, dapibus sed nibh. Nunc urna tellus, iaculis non congue id, posuere sit amet neque. Curabitur vehicula finibus orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed facilisis tortor sed mauris vehicula, vel commodo nisi faucibus. Duis sit amet euismod nisi. Duis efficitur, dolor ut ultrices accumsan, purus purus cursus felis, ac sodales libero justo efficitur magna. Morbi tellus tortor, tempor in mauris at, dapibus iaculis diam. Suspendisse condimentum magna nec libero dignissim, eu fermentum justo lobortis. Mauris ut dapibus lacus. Nullam ligula ipsum, posuere id lacus et, ultricies blandit sapien. Integer enim nisl, euismod eu venenatis a, consectetur sit amet ante. Aenean eu porta ipsum.

Aenean a lobortis massa, id efficitur tellus. Maecenas bibendum orci non imperdiet accumsan. Ut luctus magna id mi lacinia, in feugiat justo porta. Phasellus efficitur elementum tellus, in porttitor enim semper non. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam cursus justo non aliquam posuere. Nunc tempor eget dui quis rhoncus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur nec maximus nunc, condimentum accumsan massa.

Fusce justo leo, laoreet quis consectetur sed, cursus sed purus. Sed eget tincidunt velit. Donec id lectus a urna volutpat dictum. Aliquam commodo tincidunt lectus, a viverra enim. Nulla nec ante porttitor nunc sagittis tempus. Praesent volutpat porttitor est nec aliquet. Praesent aliquam aliquam leo laoreet ultricies. Mauris cursus leo at tortor ornare, et dictum libero fringilla. Ut massa est, fringilla eget nisi non, iaculis semper ligula. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut congue pellentesque arcu ac laoreet. Nam eu malesuada justo.

Ut egestas ornare tellus nec iaculis. Sed sit amet purus eu diam interdum tempus. Integer bibendum dignissim justo. Suspendisse sed arcu faucibus ex aliquet feugiat. Nulla vestibulum, felis sed ultrices varius, tellus purus rutrum diam, vitae molestie enim nulla non dui. Duis ultricies mi tortor, sed molestie sem rhoncus vel. Quisque tincidunt viverra sapien, sed tristique justo volutpat sed. Nunc tempor sit amet nulla vel tincidunt. Suspendisse pellentesque facilisis sapien id faucibus. Donec sodales finibus augue, ut volutpat est auctor sit amet. Sed rutrum, lacus at rhoncus condimentum, tortor lectus porta eros, et blandit nibh elit in diam. Pellentesque semper et metus eget posuere. Integer at velit elit. Praesent non malesuada nisl.

Duis ut lacus tellus. Vivamus aliquam magna eu sem suscipit, non bibendum mauris lobortis. Donec placerat purus eget tortor blandit, at iaculis nibh pretium. Cras quis sollicitudin erat. Ut finibus mollis sem et vehicula. Mauris rutrum gravida blandit. Sed velit mi, congue vel arcu sit amet, mollis laoreet mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce a hendrerit nunc. Pellentesque aliquam dictum arcu, eu mattis nunc consectetur nec. Fusce a malesuada turpis, in venenatis mi.

Maecenas nisl lorem, hendrerit vel dignissim id, efficitur et ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum molestie neque ut imperdiet vestibulum. Ut a felis et ligula scelerisque venenatis. Donec fermentum ex risus, ac eleifend eros tempor non. Maecenas consectetur purus eu dapibus efficitur. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque vestibulum magna quis mollis commodo. Proin sed ex mollis, rhoncus turpis cursus, laoreet augue. Maecenas non enim diam. Fusce ultricies malesuada orci. Sed dictum cursus fermentum. Nunc vehicula felis non ex congue, eget fringilla lectus fringilla. Nulla aliquam nec arcu et dictum.

Nulla tincidunt purus sapien, in semper lectus viverra sed. In vulputate ante sit amet elit placerat semper. Duis lorem tellus, tempus in leo tincidunt, iaculis commodo risus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Quisque vitae vestibulum elit. Ut facilisis lectus sed arcu dapibus facilisis id sed sapien. Nullam varius quam at enim vehicula ullamcorper. Proin nec mauris fringilla, mattis purus ac, efficitur felis. Mauris fringilla tellus non ligula ornare mollis. Aliquam pulvinar condimentum consequat. Nam sed libero non dui placerat ultricies.

Quisque pulvinar eros quis lacus dapibus vestibulum. Morbi quis orci ut nisl auctor auctor quis et dui. Fusce ex quam, aliquam at libero scelerisque, tincidunt euismod nulla. Integer vulputate dui sit amet sodales convallis. Duis porttitor nibh risus, a iaculis elit mattis suscipit. In hendrerit nibh erat, et aliquet magna cursus sit amet. Nullam libero leo, semper quis nulla id, pharetra euismod erat. Nulla vel est at lacus dictum pulvinar. Praesent pretium ante dolor, vel facilisis sapien porttitor sed. Nunc in aliquam ante. Proin consequat consectetur urna, eu pellentesque ipsum pharetra ut. Donec ultrices nisl vitae lorem suscipit consectetur. Phasellus vitae lorem et libero dapibus ullamcorper et eu mi.

Sed sagittis, tellus id congue egestas, felis magna tempor risus, nec dictum felis libero eget nunc. Maecenas id eleifend turpis. Nunc placerat odio dui, ut hendrerit tellus suscipit vitae. Morbi nunc lectus, lacinia scelerisque tortor ut, tincidunt fringilla lorem. Nullam dignissim eros eget ipsum rhoncus efficitur. Donec ac quam sodales, tempus risus vitae, aliquet lectus. Aenean non finibus risus. Mauris maximus egestas metus ut malesuada. Morbi egestas tempor tincidunt. Integer sagittis mi vitae elit sodales vestibulum. Curabitur varius dui a massa hendrerit fringilla. Pellentesque imperdiet ipsum in metus ornare sagittis. Nam eget posuere ante, id hendrerit est. Vestibulum vehicula aliquet odio et ornare. Curabitur augue diam, scelerisque vel dapibus eget, facilisis sed turpis. Morbi auctor faucibus lacus sed accumsan.

Integer consectetur dui nibh, varius ullamcorper lectus feugiat id. Vestibulum massa leo, egestas vestibulum sollicitudin in, convallis sit amet justo. Sed mauris justo, faucibus volutpat facilisis ac, volutpat non leo. Vestibulum convallis magna a massa rhoncus accumsan. Quisque et semper dui. Suspendisse euismod erat vel magna fringilla fermentum. Fusce pellentesque egestas tellus, mattis maximus metus rutrum quis. Nulla pharetra vitae turpis ut venenatis. Aliquam maximus urna nunc, sit amet posuere tellus fringilla nec.

Pellentesque viverra orci vel eros rhoncus, in feugiat elit laoreet. Donec sed nulla lorem. Donec sed ipsum eros. Vivamus metus dolor, tristique at ex sit amet, semper condimentum tortor. Vivamus et elementum libero. Phasellus laoreet lectus turpis, ac vestibulum urna finibus a. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Integer nec rhoncus enim, et congue orci. Nam rutrum non mi id vulputate. Sed sit amet nisi varius, mollis turpis ut, suscipit nunc. Maecenas varius nibh ac volutpat venenatis.

Vivamus vitae scelerisque sem, id elementum ligula. Mauris tristique vitae metus et tincidunt. Integer at porta neque, eget tincidunt nunc. Donec non lobortis lacus. Aenean ac rhoncus mauris, quis congue leo. In vel condimentum risus, eget tincidunt nibh. In sollicitudin lacinia dui, quis tempus lorem faucibus ut. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras eu est vitae metus maximus tempus ut gravida odio.

Etiam ut faucibus arcu. Praesent ac congue urna. Integer suscipit erat at elit vulputate dignissim. Praesent ornare quis nisl eu efficitur. Morbi iaculis turpis nisl, non mattis dolor molestie nec. Nullam in erat quam. Quisque eros nunc, placerat sed enim a, vestibulum ultricies diam. Vestibulum tempus volutpat ullamcorper. Morbi semper purus ultricies diam molestie faucibus. Aliquam ullamcorper viverra purus vel vehicula. Pellentesque fermentum congue libero, laoreet lobortis dui commodo sit amet. Donec vel orci id lorem faucibus convallis nec in ipsum.

Morbi nec ipsum pulvinar, interdum justo eu, vestibulum nisl. Fusce tristique blandit lacus, a lacinia lacus consectetur nec. Sed hendrerit ornare urna tincidunt euismod. Sed venenatis felis ipsum, vitae euismod nisi iaculis eu. Quisque placerat id ipsum ut scelerisque. Quisque dignissim magna dignissim magna aliquam consectetur. Integer efficitur convallis arcu, et mollis magna eleifend id. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis eleifend luctus fermentum. Cras id nisl nec urna suscipit eleifend. LAST LINE OF TEXT.</div>
<div class="fixed">FIXED CONTENT HERE</div>
```